Hibernate does not unbox values of a select query
To clarify, my issue is that I do not want to use any boxed type as this introduces a null value which is unwanted as it makes code harder to understand and to maintain. Obviously it would work if I simply declare Short in my issue type. I want to keep it short
I have a JPA query which is similar to
TypedQuery<Issue> query = entityManager.createQuery(
"""
Select id, version, occurence, description
FROM issue
""", Issue.class);

Where as Issue type looks like
public class Issue{

 ... //field definition

public Issue(UUID id, short version, Instant occurrance, String description){
 ... // field assigning
}

When executing the query, I do get a NoSuchMethodException telling me that hibernate could not map to the Issue type due a missing constructor definition of Issue.<init>(java.util.UUID,java.lang.Short,java.time.Instant,java.lang.String)
In other words, hibernate seems not to be able to do unboxing, which I find odd.
Can I somehow force unboxing or is this really a limitation with hibernate?

Btw. occurrance is spelled occurence.

@ValerijDobler thanks, it is one of those words I always get wrong :)

Just vocalize the plural, there it is more prominent. This trick also works in german ;)

It seems, that Hibernate is looking for a constructor which takes a (big) Short as the second argument.
I reckon that if you would change the signature to
public Issue(UUID id, Short version, Instant occurrance, String description){
 ... // field assigning
}

it should work.

Yes, this would work, but I do not want to introduce a uneccessary boxed value as this generally makes code harder to understand and maintain.

You can call it with the primitive and it will be auto-boxed.
